# ¿Cómo usar la función rand() en C al modularizar?

Tags: c, random

Estoy buscando ayuda ya que no puedo establecer un numero aleatorio entre 1 y 99 con la función rand, el número que me da es siempre 8 o un valor de muchos dígitos que sobrepasan el rango que establecí, o tal vez no se pueda modularizar la función rand() por algún motivo(estoy empezando a programar). Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int mostrarPistas(int a, int b);// Muestra las pistas indicando si el numero generado es mayor o menor.
int numeroAleatorio(int n);// Se genera un numero al azar entre 1 y 99

int main() {
    int Intentos = 1; // Ya con iniciar el programa tienes un intento ya que estas obligado a jugar.
    int numJug, numAleat;
    numeroAleatorio(numAleat);

    printf("Problema nivel 1: Azar basico\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nAdivine el numero generado del 0 al 99\n\n");

    do {
        printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &numJug);
        if (numAleat != numJug) {
            mostrarPistas(numAleat, numJug);
            Intentos++; // Cada vez que se muestre una pista se sumara 1 a tus intentos
        }
    } while (numAleat != numJug);
    printf("~~~ Ganaste!! El numero era %d ~~~\n", numJug);
    printf("Lo adivino en %d intentos", Intentos);

    return 0;
}

int mostrarPistas(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) {
        printf("El numero que quiere adivinar es menor\n\n");
    }
    else if (a > b) {
        printf("El numero que quiere adivinar es mayor\n\n");
    }
}

int numeroAleatorio(int n){
    srand(time(NULL));
    n = rand() % 99 + 1;
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar este problema, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es que efectivamente estás generando un número aleatorio ... pero no lo estás usando:

```
int numeroAleatorio( int n ){
```

Estás recibiendo una argumento **por copia**; eso quiere decir que cualquier cambio **dentro de la función** se queda ahí, sin ser visible desde el exterior.

Puesto que tu función *debería* retornar un `int` ... ¿ porqué no lo haces así ?

```
int numeroAleatorio( void ) {
  srand( time( NULL ) );
  return rand() % 99 + 1;
}
```

Y cambiamos adecuadamente tu `main( )`:

```
int main( ) {
  int Intentos = 1;
  int numJug, numAleat = numeroAleatorio( );
  ...
```

<sub>Es seguro que tu compilador te generó un **aviso** (*warning*) en tu función, porque declaras que retornará algo, pero no lo haces. Es conveniente repasar eso avisos, por si acaso ...</sub>

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me resolviste el problema. :)